# What is "complemented" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> In about half of the Sstates we find one or another type of
> referendum for parliamentary laws, often complemented by a financial
> referendum.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

I want to know what does "complemented" belong to? To "one or another type of referendum" or "parliamentary laws".

If the former is the case, is there two referendums for a parliamentary law? One about introduction of law, and other is financial?

If not, does the author intends to say that "one or another type of referendum" is often a "financial referendum"?

Comment: He seems to be saying that there are different kinds of referendum for parliamentary laws. About half of the states hold _one_ of these kinds, often in association with a financial referendum.